# Chrome aufofill bug

Tags: google-chrome

On our website https://refillbay.com about 6 months ago we start receive 4 digits as company name in the shipping address. It has caused some packages to bounce back to us due to wrong address.

We traced the issue to Chrome autofill. It puts the user's birthday year in the shipping address Company Name.

We added an autocomplete standard attribute and here is html code for that field:

`<input type="text" name="billingCompany" autocomplete="billing organization" />`

But we still get daily orders submitted with birthday year in this field. Happens only to Chrome.

Comment: Is this related to SO? If this is indeed an issue, you should create an issue on chrome tracker and provide a MWE

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it truly is a problem with a broken browser, it seems as suggested that it's going to be your responsibility to file a bug-report to the Chrome team. Though we can offer advice on mitigating the problem in the mean-time, assuming it is a less than shiny aspect of Chrome. As you've no doubt considered, perhaps a good idea to silently remove the auto-fill attribute for users browsing with chrome.

Although never perfect and subject to abuse you could have your back-end examine the user-agent string and if Chrome's detected, simply serve the page without the autofill active.

No need to remove it for everyone, nor is there a need to petulantly point the finger at a broken implementation of the browser. Perhaps something along the lines of "We're currently working with the Chrome team to improve the browsing experience" which, by filing a bug-report, you in fact would be doing... ;)

Comment: That's the point, we didn't have originally autocomplete attribute. 

When we start getting those birthday years in the company field about 6 months ago, originally tag looked like 
<input type="text" name="bCompany" />

then we changed it to 
<input type="text" name="billingCompany" />
birthdays were still coming

then we added official autofill specification
<input type="text" name="billingCompany" autocomplete="billing organization" />

Nothing helps. And we still receiving wrong data in the company name.

Where I can file a bug-report to the Chrome team?

Comment: @Alex - Google "file a bug-report to the Chrome team". I feel like I'm doing your job now....

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Chrome sometimes puts birth years in the Organization field. I filed a bug report here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=727740